# Which philosophical concept is parallel to Anekantavada ? Pluralism or perspectivalism? Is Anekantavada a metaphysical or an epistemological term?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, eastern-philosophy

Anekantavada in Jain philosophy means that each object or thing under scrutiny has infinitely many qualities associated with it, and language can only describe some of them. Plus, the perspective that each one of us has, is limited due to our finite cognitive faculties and sense perceptions; and none of us, from our single point of view, has access to these infinitely many properties. This concept is actually vividly demonstrated by the story of [an elephant and the blind men](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS6kb.png). Each person thinks upon inspecting a part of the elephant that he/she has got the answer regarding the object, and even though they are each true from their point of view, *only* when all the points of view of the blind men are put together and combined, do we get the full picture. Quote from wiki: "According to Jainism, no single, specific statement can describe the nature of existence and the absolute truth".

So, which philosophical concept does Anekantavada stand for? Is it pluralism or perspectivalism? Or is another term more apt? And is Anekantavada a metaphysical thesis or an epistemological one? To read more about it, see
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anekantavada

Comment: See here, 'A History of Indian Philosophy' Volume 1, Chapter 6 'The Jaina Philosophy', section 7 'The Doctrine of Relative Pluralism (anekantavada)' - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda - thank you for suggesting this source. I'm now leaning to describing Anekantavada as the existence of multiple viewpoints & significance of the context & intricacies of the world... I guess Anekantavada captures all these aspects with one word.